# Use of braces {...} in j

Tags: r, data.table

I have been studying a datacamp course called "Data Analysis in R, the data.table Way".

The instruction of the exercise is as follows,

- Select the b group without using `==`.
- Select the b and c groups.
- Select the first row of the b and c groups using mult.
- Use `by=.EACHI` and `.SD` to select the first and last row of the b and c
  groups.
- Extend the previous command to print out the group before returning
  the first and last row from it.

The layout is as follows,

```
# This is your data.table `DT`. The keys are set to `A` and `B`
DT <- data.table(A = letters[c(2,1,2,3,1,2,3)], B = c(5,4,1,9,8,8,6), C = 6:12)
setkey(DT, A, B)
# Select the `b` group
# `b` and `c` groups
# The first row of the `b` and `c` group
# `by=.EACHI` and `.SD` 
# Print out all the data in the two groups before you return
# the first and last row of each group again. Use {} and .N
```

I do understand how the first 4 to be done but then when I proceed to the last instruction I got stuck. I do not understand how `{}` can be used and eventually I found out that the solution for that is:

```
DT[c("b", "c"), {print(.SD); .SD[c(1, .N)]}, by = .EACHI]
```

I do not understand how the syntax in `j` works, may anyone explain it to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you know from reading `help("data.table")`, `j` expects

> A single column name, single expresson of column names, list() of expressions of column names, an expression or function call that evaluates to list (including data.frame and data.table which are lists, too), or (when with=FALSE) a vector of names or positions to select.

You should also read `help("{")`. `{` can combine expressions. It returns the last evaluated expression. Thus, as far as data.table is concerned it only gets handed the last expression, i.e., `.SD[c(1, .N)]`, and it knows what to do with that (e.g., combine the results for each group). data.table doesn't need to know what to do with `print(.SD)`, which however is evaluated within the data.table's frame.

Comment: Hi Roland, I still don't really understand what the use of the former expression (which is print(.SD) in the case) is, may you explain it more to me? Thanks.

Comment: `print(.SD)` prints the subset of the data.table to the console, which is apparently what you wanted. So, I don't understand what is unclear to you.

Comment: Thanks Roland. I thought the first expression in {} would be invisible but then when I tried some simple example (e.g. `{print(1), 1+1}`) it gets 1 and 4 printed out.

Comment: It would be invisible if it wasn't a call to `print` (or `cat` or `message` or `plot`).