# Create a column and reference it to create another column simultaneously in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Apologies in advance if this has already been asked, I could not find anything related to it when searching online.

In `dplyr`, it is possible to use `mutate` to create a column and, within the same `mutate` statement, use the newly constructed column to create another column. For example (note that this may not be the best example, but am just trying to illustrate the issue)

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), 
                b = c(4,5,6))

df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(A = a * a, 
                B = A * b)
```

returns

```
  a b A  B
1 1 4 1  4
2 2 5 4 20
3 3 6 9 54
```

Here, we see that the column `A` was constructed and then simultaneously used in the definition of `B`, all within the same `mutate` statement.

However, when trying to do the same in `data.table` it doesn't work, as the following shows

```
dt = data.table(df)

dt[, `:=` (A = a * a, 
           B = A * b)]

Error in eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : object 'A' not found
```

and calling `get(A)` in the definition of `B` shows the issue lies there. It seems that the columns needs to be constructed in separate pieces i.e `dt[, A := a * a][, B := A * b]`. This also seems to be the way the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html) describes it (section 3a, construction of the `speed` and `max_speed` columns).

The problem with this is that when working with large numbers of rows and groups, if columns are constructed by groups, it is inefficient to either make two calls to the group or to do the same operation twice

```
dt[, A := a * a, by = "group"][, B := A * b, by = "group"] # two group calls
dt[, `:=` (A := a * a, B = a * a * b), by = "group"]       # two a * a calls
```

So, I was wondering if it was possible to do this in data.table or if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
dt[, c("A", "B") := {x = a * a; .(x, x * b)}]

       a     b     A     B
   <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:     1     4     1     4
2:     2     5     4    20
3:     3     6     9    54
```

Comment: Yes I think that is doing what I was looking to do. Could you explain the syntax? As I read it, `x` is constructed from `a`, then `list()` is called on `x` through `.()` and the elements of the list are multiplied by the elements of `b`, though I do not understand the need for the parenthesis, nor why using the functional form for assigning the columns does not seem to work. It also seems somewhat verbose, though I am no data.table expert so I could be wrong.

Comment: Could do: `df[, c("A", "B") := {A = a*a; list(A, B = a*b)}]`

Comment: For anyone that is interested, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32244033/5471451) briefly explains why use of braces to contain the expression is needed. After searching, I also came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56351378/5471451) which also uses braces to simultaneously compute and reference columns in the same way I was hoping for.